# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: linux, docker, debian-stretch

I'm on a debian strech 9 server, Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40.

I've been trying to use a simple docker command "docker ps" and i keep getting that err msg stated in the title,i've looked for similar fixes yet none seemed to work, for some reason the commands such as "shutdown", or "service docker stop" won't work returning the following err :
bash: shutdown: command not found.

Stopping Docker: dockerstart-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 13454: No such process
No process in pidfile '/var/run/docker-ssd.pid' found running; none killed.

I don't know from where should i proceed, i'm opened to any suggestions

Comment: Have you tried all this as root?

Comment: yes i have i get the same err msg

Comment: what is sudo service docker status showing?

Comment: service docker status returns [FAIL] Docker is not running ... failed!
and i try to launch it using service docker start returning :[ ok ] Starting Docker: docker. but when i check on the status again it returns a fail msg

Comment: same here on WSL with debian, the problem is why the PID is not created.