# Create database from one docker container in another

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a program that builds servers automatically whenever we want stakeholders to test a new feature.

Currently I have the following setup:

1. Container 1 - all (contains nodejs, php and other dependencies)
2. Container 2 - db (contains the mysql database)

I'm aware that container 1 should be split but this will involve more unnecessary complexity  to this stage of development.

Whenever a new feature is completed and ready to be deployed to a stage server we run: `yarn run create:server --branchName=new-feature`. This will create all of the configuration necessary to bring up our newly created server.

My problem is that whenever I run the command above I need to create a database in `db` container from `all` container:

```
mysql -u root -pxxxx -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `xxxx`"
```

The script `main.ts` is running in the context of `all` container, so it is necessary for `all` to communicate with `db`.

```js
export const createDatabase = (subdomain: string) => {
  const username = process.env.DB_USERNAME;
  const password = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;

  console.log(`[INFO] Creating database with name \`${subdomain}\``);
  // triple back slash is necessary to avoid `command substitution` in some shells
  if (isLocalEnviroment()) {
    execSync(`docker run -it stage-manager-db mysql -u ${username} -p${password} -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \\\`${subdomain}\\\`"`)
  } else {
    execSync(`mysql -u ${username} -p${password} -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \\\`${subdomain}\\\`"`)
  }
  console.log(`[INFO] Database \`${subdomain}\` created successfully`);
}
```

On local environment we would like to use docker, while in production everything will sit in the same machine (db, frontendapp and api).

When trying to run the following command `docker run -it stage-manager-db mysql -u root -ppassword -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS master"` from `all` I get

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

I have tried restarting the service with:

```
service docker restart
```

which gives

```
[ ok ] Starting Docker: docker.
```

but trying to communicate with `db` from `all` keeps getting the same error. Upon trying to `service docker stop` I get:

```
[....] Stopping Docker: dockerstart-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 825: No such process
No process in pidfile '/var/run/docker-ssd.pid' found running; none killed.
 failed!
```

From now on I have tried the several links to fix this issue:

- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/52#issuecomment-333563492
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146634/how-to-remove-docker-from-windows-subsystem
- [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350683/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock)
- [Cant uninstall Docker from Ubuntu on WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377291/cant-uninstall-docker-from-ubuntu-on-wsl/51939517)

How can I communicate from `all` container to `db` container?

## Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libxrender1 \
    libpng-dev \
    make \
    nginx \
    apt-transport-https \
    gnupg2 \
    wget \
    procps \
    docker.io

# Install nodejs
RUN apt -y install curl dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt -y install nodejs

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql exif zip pcntl gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt update && apt install yarn

# Install dependencies for this project
RUN yarn global add ts-node typescript

RUN useradd -m forge

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=forge:forge . /var/forge

# Copy ssh keys
COPY ./config/ssh /home/forge/.ssh/

# Give right permissions to `ssh` keys
RUN chmod 600 /home/forge/.ssh/config
RUN chmod 600 /home/forge/.ssh/back_end_deploy_key
RUN chmod 600 /home/forge/.ssh/frontend_deploy_key
RUN chmod 644 /home/forge/.ssh/back_end_deploy_key.pub
RUN chmod 644 /home/forge/.ssh/frontend_deploy_key.pub
RUN chown forge:forge /home/forge/.ssh/*

# Up Docker
RUN service docker start
RUN usermod -aG docker forge

# Create folder for stage servers
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/stage-servers

# Give correct permissions to `stage-servers` folder
RUN chown forge:www-data /var/www/stage-servers
RUN chmod g+s /var/www/stage-servers
RUN chmod o-rwx /var/www/stage-servers

# Change current user to forge
USER forge

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

## docker-composer.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  all:
    working_dir: /var/www/stage-manager
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/stage-manager"
      - "./config/ssh:/root/.ssh"
    networks:
      - main

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: stage-manager-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: whatever
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
    networks:
      - main
volumes:
  project:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/
      o: bind
  dbdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  main:
```

I'm fairly new to docker so any approach that I might be doing wrong, please let me know. I have a feeling that this could be done much better so feel free to suggest improvements.

Comment: Not pretty sure, but you can try `docker exec -it all mysql -u root -password -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS master"`. Run this command not from any container, but from the host running docker. Being `all` the name of the container.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a `docker` command to communicate with a database, especially from a language that has native database libraries.  Can you open an ordinary MySQL connection (with the environment-specific host name specified by an environment variable) instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze Have tried so many times trying to go down the path you have described but ended up giving up on the assumption that a socket would solve the problem. After your comment on my own answer I will pursue the path of installing `mysql-client` then. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Update

** DO NOT DO THIS **

**Instead of deleting this answer I will leave it here so others can see that this is not a secure/valid solution to this problem**

By David Maze's comment:

> Remember that anyone who can access the Docker socket has unrestricted root-level access over the whole host system. I would not add the Docker socket in casually here.

---

I was able to make it working by sharing the `socket` between my host OS and the `all` container.

## docker-compose.yml

```
all:
    working_dir: /var/www/stage-manager
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www/stage-manager"
      - "./config/ssh:/root/.ssh"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" -> important part
    networks:
      - main
```

Comment: Remember that anyone who can access the Docker socket has unrestricted root-level access over the whole host system.  I would not add the Docker socket in casually here.

Comment: Humm.. Didn't know that. Thank you David. Will update the answer and include your comment